# I would like to block the Windows folder from Standard User accounts

Tags: windows-7, file-permissions

I am running Windows 7 Professional. I'd like to block the HOSTS file from being changed by a Standard User account. How do I do this?

Comment: This can be done by a local group policy but really the default User group already has restricted access to this folder anyways.

Comment: Just to build on the above, you could move users to new User groups then follow @DBZ_A's answer to apply permissions for that group to a folder

Comment: The default security permissions for the hosts file are the following: `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F) BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F) BUILTIN\Users:(I)(RX)` As you can see, standard users only have (inherited) read and execute access.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible through right clicking the folder > Properties >Security tab. Set permissions for each user. I am not too sure if you can block write access altogether since some programs may need to write to windows directory. Maybe you can just hide the folder using hidden/system attributes and selecting not to show hidden or system files in folder options.

Comment: How about just the hosts file write properties?

Comment: Change the file permissions in file properties>security. Remove write permission for required users. This wouldn't break any other program IMO. In my machine by default hosts file is read-only for normal users.